# Wordpress - alterar título do post no header da página

Tags: wordpress

Neste link: http://wp.ubiqui.com.br/2017/05/24/central-de-marketplaces/ vocês verão que sobre a imagem está o título do post. 
Gostaria de colocar um código no Wordpress para que, apenas quando acessar um post, ele troque para "Notícias".
Nas demais páginas, é para ficar do jeito que está.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode usar o filtro "wp_title". No seu arquivo functions.php você pode inserir algo como:

```
function trocar_titulo($title){
    if(is_single()){
        return "Notícias";
    }
    return $title;
}
add_filter( 'wp_title', 'trocar_titulo', 10, 2 );
```

Ref: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_title/